# difference between console.log and $log in Ionic Cordova App

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have a project I've inherited and throughout the app.. we're seeing

`console.log("blah blah");`

when I read about Ionic and Cordova.. I understand we're given a logger via

`$log.error()`

Anyone care to chime in as to what the difference is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of them are quite equivalent. I have never used $log service though, but you if you go through the number of available methods with each, they are the same :

- info
- warn
- debug
- error
- log

Some developers even reported for inconsistent behaviour of $log service. You can find the related text [here](http://www.betsmartmedia.com/what-i-learned-building-an-app-with-ionic-framework)